# The service connection does not exist or has not been authorized for use

Tags: azure-devops

I'm trying to create my first release pipeline, however I keep getting this error:

> Exception Message: The pipeline is not valid. Job Phase_1: Step AzureResourceGroupDeployment input ConnectedServiceName references service connection 
>   which could not be found. The service connection does not exist or has not been authorized for use. For authorization details, 
>   refer to https://aka.ms/yamlauthz. (type PipelineValidationException)

I've tried to follow the instructions in the link, however the "Authorize Resources" button does not exist.

"Allow all pipelines to use this service connection" is already enabled and I have recreated the deployment task after enabling this.

How do I authorise the resource?

Comment: What about re-create the YAML or create the release with classic editor?

Comment: @MerlinLiang-MSFT How do I use the classic editor? I can't see an option for it

Comment: When you create one new pipeline. In the first page, do not choose YAML. Focus on the last line “Use the classic editor to create the first pipeline”. Click this.

Comment: @MerlinLiang-MSFT I don't see the option, I can only see "New Release Pipeline"

Comment: This is the Classic Editor type. What I mentioned in previous comment is for build. What about create deploy task with this classic editor type?

Comment: @MerlinLiang-MSFT How do I access the classic editor for releases?

Comment: If you create the release from the button "New release pipeline" this is the classic editor for release.

Comment: @MerlinLiang-MSFT in which case I've always been using this option, but I still have this issue.

Comment: What about verify the connection from here? https://imgur.com/a/jHmRUSB Sometime, when you ever authorized once, it will not need you authorized it again. That's why you could not see this button.

Comment: @MerlinLiang-MSFT Verify connection works fine

Comment: Can we talk in room? https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200604/for-service-conenction. I need share some troubleshooting method for you, and collect some details.

Comment: @MerlinLiang-MSFT I think I've found a solution, please see the answer

Comment: Seen it. But still wired the previous service connection could not be used. Does that same with the current configuration? If you want to dig the root cause, you can collect fiddler trace to analyze it. Or send the email to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My "Service connection" which defined the service principal connection had been created separately to the task in my release pipeline.

In order for "Authorize Resources" to occur, you must create a new connection from the task itself (you may need to use the advanced options to add an existing service principal).

1. under "Azure subscription" click the name of the subscription you wish to use
2. Click the drop down next to "Authorize" and open advanced options
3. Click " use the full version of the service connection dialog."
4. Enter all your credentials and hit save

Answer (score 17):

I had the same issue, and I initally missed the fact that you need to click the 'Authorize resources' button that appears, as shown below

[image]

Also in my case, my pipeline was missing variables that included the correct service connection name. These were set up in a variable group that was already being used by another pipeline. I needed to link them in my new pipeline:

Edit pipeline > select elipsis at top right > triggers > Variables > Variable groups > Link variable group

Comment: ah - linking the variable group was my issue

Comment: That setting is very hidden and not obvious. This was my issue as well.

Answer (score 4):

You can either use existing Service principal or create a new one. All you need is in documentation already.
[Create an Azure Resource Manager service connection using automated security](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/connect-to-azure?view=azure-devops)

From Azure DevOps -> Project setting -> Service connection: Then click on "New Service Connection".Choose "Azure resource Manager" as type of service connection. Select Service Principal (Automatic). Run your pipeline

Answer (score 4):

The admittely *silly* solution for me was to avoid declaring and using the Service Connection as a variable, i.e. in the case of connecting to an Azure Container Registry:

Failed

```
pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-20.04'

variables:
  dockerRegistryServiceConnection: 'my-service-connection'
  baseContainerUrl: 'myregistry.azurecr.io/my_image:latest'

container:
  image: $(baseContainerUrl)
  endpoint: $(dockerRegistryServiceConnection)
```

Worked

```
pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-20.04'

variables:
  baseContainerUrl: 'myregistry.azurecr.io/my_image:latest'

container:
  image: $(baseContainerUrl)
  endpoint: my-service-connection
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I was trying to use `[AzureAppServiceSettings][1]` task, and was using
`azureSubscription` with subscription id in the YAML file.

The YAML file

```
  - task: AzureAppServiceSettings@1
    displayName: Update App Settings of the Logic App
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: '$(azureSubscriptionId)'
      resourceGroupName: ...
      appName: ...
      appSettings: ...
```

I got the same error and after clicking Authorise resources, I got error of `no plan found for identifier xxxx`.

[image]
[image]

Needed to change my YAML file to use connection name in Azure DevOps.

```
  - task: AzureAppServiceSettings@1
    displayName: Update App Settings of the Logic App
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: 'Nonprod Connection'
      resourceGroupName: ...
      appName: ...
      appSettings: ...
```

So `Nonprod Connection` is one of my service connections in Azure Devops.

After fixing the value of azureSubscription, the pipeline doesn't show up the error anymore.

Answer (score 1):

In ["classic release pipelines"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/releases?view=azure-devops), a *release* is a snapshot of a *release pipeline*, with all the settings of the pipeline materialized, and a *deployment* is the execution of a pipeline *stage* in the release.

In our case, a release generating this error during deployment predated a service principal renewal. We could [edit the release](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/?view=azure-devops#when-should-i-edit-a-release-instead-of-the-pipeline-that-defines-it) to use the new service principal and successfully deploy the modified release. The release pipeline did not need modifications.

1. Navigate to the release overview of the relevant release.

   - `https://dev.azure.com/<user>/<project>/_releaseProgress?...`
2. Select *Edit* > *Edit release*.
3. Click *Edit tasks* for the relevant stage.
4. Select the *Azure App Service Deploy* step.
5. Choose the correct *Azure subscription* and *App Service name* values.

   - These values will likely be the same as in the release pipeline
   - In our case these fields were empty and "needed attention".
6. Click *Save*.
7. Click *Deploy*.

The changes persist, so the corrected release can be deployed a second time without incident.

It is [unclear whether this applies to YAML pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/get-started/key-pipelines-concepts?view=azure-devops#release) but I would guess no.

Comment: I can confirm that we faced the "same" thing. We had a pipeline that was working, did a minor change and it failed with the mentioned error. A revert didn't help. Doing an edit on the deployment, changing to another Service Connection, saving - and selecting the original service connection again, saving. Continue the deployment and voilà - It worked again...

Answer (score 1):

I was having this error because I was declaring the variable group containing the service connection name at stage level.

The error was fixed once I declared the variable group at pipeline level.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and noticed that adding a task to run an Azure PowerShell script was also getting a similar error.
Turned out that the problem was solved when I verified the service connection twice within the project that was having the problem:

[image: Verify screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

[kubernetesServiceConnection-Code-Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BqQei.png).
I faced the same issue when tried to pass the service connection value from `variable/parameter/library group`. If I pass directly then I am not facing this issue.

**Solution:**  When we want to pass the service connection from `variable/parameter/library` group then make sure the variable key name is the same as required in the task.

For example, I am passing service connection name of a k8s clustr.
In the task the key is `kubernetesServiceConnection` .

Refer to [HelmDeploy@0](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/helm-deploy-v0?view=azure-pipelines) documentation.

so my `variable/parameter` name will also be same.
For example,

```
parameters:
   environment: 'inception          
   kubernetesServiceEndpoint: 'abc'
```

[Final Code Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wxsax.png)

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

A solution suggested on https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-devops/azure-devops-error-some-recent-issues-detected-related-to/m-p/3050626/highlight/true#M270 worked for me.

> Edit -> Settings: Point the pipeline file to a different yaml, save, then point back to the correct yaml file